# Default selected index for combo-box crashes my UWP App

Tags: uwp, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml, c++-cx

Why the default selected index doesn't work? It crashes with platform exception :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="dCmbControl" x:Uid="dCmbControl" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{x:Bind abc}"/>
```

RumTime Error :

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDEF7F7788 (KernelBase.dll) in abc.exe: 0x40080201: WinRT originate error (parameters: 0x00000000802B000A, 0x000000000000003E, 0x00000066746FBB90).
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDEF7F7788 in abc.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Platform::COMException ^ at memory location 0x00000066746FC0E0. HRESULT:0x802B000A The text associated with this error code could not be found.
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try to set dCmbControl.SelectedIndex = -1 on page initialization instead of xaml

Comment: Try to set `ItemsSource` and after that setup `SelectedIndex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `SelectedIndex` set to 0, the `ComboBox` is trying to access its first child to select it. When the XAML is loading, the control is built and `SelectedIndex` is initialized to 0. This will update the related `SelectedItem` property but since, there is still no items available at this point, an exception is raised.

Unfortunately, the raised exception does not contains any details about this (it is the same in C#).

You can either set the value to `-1` in the XAML and update it to what you want once the combobox is loaded (either through the code behind or through the binding).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. 
What I did was manually add the items from the list (The same list as i used in the x:bind) to the combobox just before i needed to set it. This way it is always loaded when you need it.